# NodeMCU lua function "conn"

Tags: lua, mqtt, esp8266, nodemcu

I have maybe a weird question but I need to know this. Im creating a lua script to connect esp8266 and my mqtt broker. The example script is very straight forward.

```
m = mqtt.Client("clientid", 120, "user", "password")

m:lwt("/lwt", "offline", 0, 0)

m:on("connect", function(con) print ("connected") end)
m:on("offline", function(con) print ("offline") end)

m:on("message", function(conn, topic, data) 
  print(topic .. ":" ) 
  if data ~= nil then
    print(data)
  end
end)

m:connect("192.168.11.118", 1880, 0, function(conn) 
    print("connected") 
end)

m:subscribe("/topic",0, function(conn) 
    print("subscribe success") 
end)

m:publish("/topic","hello",0,0, function(conn) 
    print("sent") 
end)

m:close();
```

But... there is one thing I can't get over. That is the "con" and "conn" parameter? It looks like an instance or something, but there is no such a thing defined. Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/wiki/nodemcu_api_en#mqttclienton) you can find that the client's `on()` method registers a callback where the first param is the client itself. For your convenience (and in case the link dies) I have copied the relevant information below:

## mqtt.client:on()

### Description

register callback function to event.

### Syntax

`mqtt:on(event, function(client, [topic], [message]))`

### Parameters

`event`
string, which can be: "connect", "message", "offline"

`function(client, [topic], [message])`
callback function. The first param is the client.
If event is "message", the 2nd and 3rd param are received topic and message in string.

### Returns

nil.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But where is that client defined? There is just instance "m". And why there is once "con" and once "conn"? Everything is working, I just want to fully understand.

Comment: m is the client instance, which was created when you called `mqtt.Client(...)` and that is exactly what is being passed to the callback. con and conn is just what you have named the parameter.  
Try adding `print(con==m)` into one of the callbacks and you'll see they are the same.

Comment: @jevniky if this is solved then please accept this answer so that StackOverflow can mark it solved.